# Order of Files collection in FileSystemObject

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

In VBScript, I want to get a list of files in a folder ordered by creation date. I saw that in order to do that I will need to either use a record set (seems like an overkill to me) or sort the collection myself (I think I can avoid it and I want my code to be shorter).

Since I am the one creating the files, I create them with names that begin with the date (yyyy_mm_dd) so I though that if I can get the files at least ordered by name then I'm all set. Unfortunately, the [MSDN documentation of the Files collection from FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18b41306%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) doesn't say anything about the order of the collection. Does anyone know of some other secret documentation or something like that that can be more specific?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get the files in a folder in a specific order, you'll have to do it yourself. If you don't like the ADO recordset or using a sortable .NET collection, you can shell out (.Run, .Exec) and process the output of `dir /A:-D /B /O:D /T:C` (no folders, bare format (no header/summary), order:date, timefield:creation).

**Update:**

While I surely can show examples where the .Files collection delivered its elements ordered by name, Mr. Gates explicitly [says](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/189/Q189751/):

> INFO: Limitations of the FileSystemObject ... Cannot sort file names
>   from the files collection - you can iterate through the File objects
>   in the Files collection to obtain a list of the files in a folder.
>   However, the File objects are not sorted. You need to use a sort
>   routine to sort the File objects in the Files collection.

Minimalistic demo code that shows: You need a shell (%comspec%) if you want to use shell features - like [intrinsic commands](http://elearning.algonquincollege.com/coursemat/viljoed/gis8746/concepts/dosbatch/advanced/intrin1.htm):

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS  : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim goWS  : Set goWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim csDir : csDir = "c:\temp"

WScript.Quit demoSF()

Function demoSF()
  demoSF = 0
  Dim aDSOrd : aDSOrd = getDSOrd(csDir, "%comspec% /c dir /A:-D /B /O:D /T:C """ & csDir & """")
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In aDSOrd
      WScript.Echo oFile.DateCreated, oFile.Name
  Next
End Function ' demoSF

Function getDSOrd(sDir, sCmd)
  Dim dicTmp : Set dicTmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim oExec  : Set oExec  = goWS.Exec(sCmd)
  Do Until oExec.Stdout.AtEndOfStream
     dicTmp(goFS.GetFile(goFS.BuildPath(sDir, oExec.Stdout.ReadLine()))) = Empty
  Loop
  If Not oExec.Stderr.AtEndOfStream Then
     WScript.Echo "Error:", oExec.Stderr.ReadAll()
  End If
  getDSOrd = dicTmp.Keys()
End Function
```

Output:

```
cscript 16895525.vbs
07.10.1998 15:31:34 TlbInf32.chm
..
09.10.2008 22:40:29 sqlce.sql
09.10.2008 22:40:29 gltsqlcopytest.sdf
05.11.2008 20:11:39 Vorfuehrung.class
..
28.03.2011 20:23:36 Program.cs
.
01.10.2012 10:10:10 KyXHDe.chm
```

Comment: As a suggestion: I'd add `/b` to the argument list to avoid needless detail in the output.

Comment: I saw that option also and thought about it but wouldn't I have to output the results of the `dir` command to a file and then process that file? I tried using "Exec" but it looked as if it can only execute an executable and such (like "ping.exe") and it didn't work with `dir` (I couldn't find any `dir.com` file on Windows 7, maybe on Windows XP?). I'm worried that if I use create and use external files I might end up with some synchronization issues and locked files that can't be deleted, failing my script.

How can the "dir" option be done without creating a file (by ">>")?

Comment: Also, I can manage without setting the order of the files myself if I can be sure the "Files" collection returns them ordered by file name (so far, I didn't see any official documentation about it so I'm not assuming anything).

Comment: So there is a "secret" documentation regarding the order of the `Files` collection. They should add that to the MSDN article. Too bad there's nothing simpler but that will do great. I was starting to regret choosing VBScript because it is already there and shouldn't require anything else installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Is it really too much code to sort?

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set outputLines = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
for each f in fso.GetFolder(".").files
  outputLines.Add f.Name
next
outputLines.Sort() ' 5 lines...

For Each outputLine in outputLines
  set file = fso.GetFolder(".").files.item (outputLine&"")
  Wscript.Echo file.name ' TODO: your thing here
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.

It is short but since it is using a .net object the script may have problems in the future when there are .net upgrades (though it is unlikely with such a basic class as the ArrayList).

I want to have this script scheduled to run once a day and probably no one is going to be there to handle problems - so I want to minimize the risk.

Comment: The question is about file object by date and this sorts a collections of names, by name.

Comment: And ArrayList requires .Net 3.5 which is no longer installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the accepted answer except that the file list is put into an array instead of a scripting dictionary. The order can be set by simply changing the `Order` constant to any order supported by the `DIR` command, such as `/oen` (order first by extension and then by name).

```
Const Folder = "C:\Test"
Const FileList = ".\FileList.txt"
Const Order = "/od /tc" 'Set DIR command order here
Const ForReading = 1

Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oWSH.CurrentDirectory = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

oWSH.Run "Cmd /c dir /b /a-d " & Order & " """ & Folder & "\*.*"">""" & FileList & """",0,True

FileContents = ""
On Error Resume Next
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(FileList,ForReading)
FileContents = oFile.ReadAll
oFile.Close
On Error Goto 0
If FileContents="" Then
  MsgBox "No files found in folder:" & VBCRLF & VBCRLF & Folder,vbOKonly,WScript.ScriptName
  WScript.Quit
End If

ArrFiles = Split(FileContents,VBCRLF)
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFiles)
  WScript.Echo ArrFiles(i)
Next
```